# Something is multiplying by 2 and I don't know where it is coming from

Tags: differential-equations

In my code when calculating u[x,t], for some reason all of the coefficients c[j] are getting doubled, and Idk from where! Not only that, all iterations of the sum are not being calculated. What I am doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Please post your code (instead of an image of the code). It makes it a lot easier to help if we can copy-paste your code and try things.

Comment: I will do so from now on Bill. I have found the problem though. I edited the OP.

Comment: @MatthewDelengowski I think your question could be safely deleted at this point. Your problem was rather specific to your setup, so the question is likely to be closed anyway. Alternatively, since you were able to pinpoint the source of trouble, you could write a self-answer detailing your solution (those are encouraged on SE sites), rather than including it in the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

[`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) will find all of the roots in an interval

```
roots = x /. NSolve[{Tan[x] == -x, 2 <= x <= 36.50}, 
    x, Reals];

f[x_] = x (1 - x);

c[root_?NumericQ] :=
  NIntegrate[f[x]*Sin[root*x], {x, 0, 1}]/
   NIntegrate[Sin[root*x]^2, {x, 0, 1}];

coeff = c /@ roots;
```

Since the components of the definition of `u[x, t]` are [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html)

```
u[x_, t_] = Total[coeff*Sin[roots*x]*Exp[-roots^2*t]];

Plot[Evaluate@{f[x], u[x, 0]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1.7/2.7,
 PlotLegends -> {"f[x]", "u[x, 0]"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the Findroot function. Well its not the function, it is my guesses. Findroot uses Newtons Methods for approximating roots. Its very fickle to the guesses, and it was giving me roots I already gotten. I had to be more precise with my guesses. Below are more correct guesses, and everything works out.

[image]

Comment: Please include the actual code in your answer, not an image.